# Where can I find a PPA for fcron?

Tags: 11.10, package-management, ppa, cron

According to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+package/fcron it seems that there is a version of fcron available for 11.10, but reffering to http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/packages/show/329892 it seems that fcron was removed from the repos. Also I cant find it in synaptics.

Is there an easy way to install fcron side by side with cron via PPA? If possible I would be happy if I could avoid selfcompiling it.

Comment: according to this page - upstream abandoned the project... hence why it was deleted from the repos.  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/i386/fcron/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The User fossfreedom mentioned in a comment a link to [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/i386/fcron/).

In this link is a statement that the fcron project is not under developement any more, also the [homepage of fcron itself](http://fcron.free.fr/) shows that there was no release since May 2010, also there was a gap of three years to the release before.

I could not find a quick way to contact the developement team to ask if the project is really abondoned, so I assume it is and try to live with cron until I find another solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is again activity on the [fcron website](http://fcron.free.fr/).

```
03/03/2013  fcron 3.1.2 released
01/01/2013  fcron 3.1.1 released
12/19/2012  fcron 3.1.0 released
12/05/2012  fcron git repository
04/05/2010  fcron 3.0.6 released
```

The author, Thibault Godouet, can be reached on the development mailing list: fcrondev@ml.free.fr, or at his personal email address: fcron@free.fr. Developers usually prefer a mailing list.

I will reach out and try to contact the author, to ask him to put it back into Debian. Once it's in Debian, it will eventually end up in Ubuntu too.

Comment: It is not available in Debian nor Ubuntu at the time of writing: https://tracker.debian.org/news/495078, https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fcron